# Open file on specific row without VBA

Tags: excel

I have a specific question.

I manage a calendar on Excel for several person to open. As it is shared by many person I don't want to use VBA

According to the date of the opening I would like to open on the row of the date.
But if the date is out of list I want it to open on first row.

Is it possible to do it without VBA?

Thanks for replies

Comment: `Is it possible to do it without VBA?` probably not.  Formulas cannot change the row that is at the top.  This will require vba in a workbook_open event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced filtering with some helper columns to do this.

I'm using Sheet 3 and 4 Columns A through D. Modify the formulas as needed.

I'm using this setup:

| Item | Date | Helper 1 | Helper 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Helper Column 1:

```
=IF(AND(B2=Sheet4!$B$2,COUNTIF(B2:B14,Sheet4!$B$2)),1,0)
```

Helper Column 2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$14,1) > 0,1,0)
```

[image]

On another sheet you need to set up the advanced filters. Use the same headers as your data.
First row under headers:

Date: `=Today()`

Second row under headers:

Item: 1

Helper 1: 0

Helper 2: 0

Go to Data --> Sort & Filter --> Advanced

List range = Your table
Criteria Range = the criteria table you just set up.

All together with the date present:

[image]

Without Date present:

[image]

I'm unsure how to get it to update automatically without VBA, you may need to instruct them to hit the advanced filter button to get it to update.